# Redirect pipe to a variable in Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to stop and start a Windows service from a remote PC using the Windows command line, in a batch file.

```
sc \\192.168.1.1 stop <ServiceName>

rem sc \\192.168.1.1 query <ServiceName> | findstr STATUS | SET VAR=
```

However, I want to wait until the status of the service is assured to be stopped or started. So I was planning to loop and check the status continuously until the status is STOPPED.

I think that repeated request to the server may be processor intensive but there is no wait for the command line except for some hacks on checking time. But my main question is how do I get the status of the Windows service so I can check with an IF statement if it is OK to proceed to the next command?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To set a variable to the output of a command, use `for /f`:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('command') do set _CmdResult=%%a
```

The problem is, to use a pipe in the command you need to escape it with the command line escape character: `^`, therefore: `^|`.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('sc \\192.168.1.1 query <ServiceName> ^| findstr STATUS') do set _CmdResult=%%a
```

Now, I'm not sure which version of Windows you're running, but my attempts at a `sc` query on Windows 7 give the following output:

```
>sc query SamSs
SERVICE_NAME: SamSs
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

This means a `findstr STATE` would be required, which gives the output:

```
>sc query SamSs | findstr STATE
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
```

Now, in the example above, `tokens=*` means every token is set to the variable `%%a`, where tokens are separated by spaces. In this case, you can use either the third token (`4`) or fourth token (`RUNNING`). By the way, with testing, `1` corresponds to `STOPPED` for me.

To make things easier, I'll be using the string `RUNNING` in this example. So we want the fourth token.

```
for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('sc \\192.168.1.1 query <ServiceName> ^| findstr STATE') do set _CmdResult=%%a
```

Of course, depending on what your `sc query` outputs, yours may be slightly different, so follow how I got there and modify as needed. Or post in a comment the output of your `sc query` and I'll modify as needed.

To check the value, you can use:

```
if %_CmdResult%==STOPPED (
    REM do something here
)
```

In your case, the loop would go something like this.

```
:loop
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('sc \\192.168.1.1 query <ServiceName> ^| findstr STATUS') do set _CmdResult=%%a
if %_CmdResult%==STOPPED (
    sc \\192.168.1.1 start <ServiceName>
    goto endloop
)
timeout /t 5
goto loop
:endloop
```

Note that `timeout` is a utility only included in Windows Vista and later. Windows XP can use [something like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos) `ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul`.

Comment: Thanks Bob, It was very detailed. But I guess the tiny bit that was missing in my code was the escaped pipe using the caret character. But this would be helpful for future reference. :)

Comment: Thanks for `^|` I was getting `| was unexpected at this time.` without it.

Comment: thank you so much for the ^| !!

Comment: I don't understand how the `tokens=*` and `tokens=4` parameter works - can you explain it?

Comment: @Dai It's a bit much to explain in comments, but the `for /?` help text is quite descriptive, and [this website](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) has rather detailed descriptions. If you need further explanation, asking a new question might be useful. In short, `tokens=4` gets you the 4th space-delimited field from the command output. `tokens=*` gets you the entire line.

Answer (score 3):

### A More advanced example with higher complexity level

### *(but also higher usability)*

- using several common application (`cURL`, `GREP`, `SED`) <sub>you can either download a Win32 pre-build versions of those or use **cygwin**'s exe files in Windows- **both works perfectly fine** (for cygwin, better just put `c:\cygwin\bin\` folder location in your system's `PATH` variable for easier access).</sub>
- PIPE processing (STDOUT and STDERR are processed through).
- escaped symbols (`|`, `>`, `&`)  <sub>- best practice / required on Windows7+.</sub>
- *no loops*, *no goto*
- working with numeric data (`curl`'s response header `Content-Length`)
- ## *And..* NO TEMPORARY FILES!

---

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions
  for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('curl --head --ipv4 --sslv3 --silent --location-trusted --url "https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/Win_x64/362418/mini_installer.exe" 2^>^&1 ^| grep "Content-Length" 2^>^&1 ^| sed "s/\r\n$//g" 2^>^&1 ^| sed "s/content-length\:\ //gi" 2^>^&1') do ( set /a num=%%a )

  set /a num=%num% / 1024 / 1024

  echo it is %num%MB
endlocal
```

will output
**`it is 41MB`**

(original header is **`Content-Length: 43597312`**)

---

***took it from here: 
 - [CMD/Bash Script Ninja - cURL Response Header Number Manipulation](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/curl-and-cmd-fun-response-headers-manipulation-shell-script/)***

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) by Microsoft (Sysinternals). There is an tool called [PsService](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542) where you can remotely check the services via the parameter `\\computer`